# Error inflating class fragment. Can anyone explain why this error occurs out of nowhere

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-studio, android-layout

[[image: Error inflating class fragment. Can anyone explain why this error occurs nowhere? I'm not getting why didn't it show at first why this happened when it was running before]][Error inflating class fragment. Can anyone explain why this error occurs nowhere? I'm not getting why didn't it show at first why this happened when it was running before]

Comment: Could u post your `fragment_dashboard.xml` layout file to see?

Comment: android:id="@+id/map1"   is in line 17, I just simply changed map1 into map_one and the error is gone. Hopefully, no one has to face this...

Answer (score 1):

Please share your fragment file and check if you are providing correct resource as it is giving resource not found please check that also

Answer (score 0):

android:id="@+id/map1" is in line 17, which was the fragment id. I just simply changed map1 into map_one and the error is gone. Hopefully, no one has to face this...